# Netlify CMS date field is showing a glitch / error

Tags: momentjs, content-management-system, netlify-cms

My date field in Netlify is showing `08/19/2022 fam8/19/202205`. How do I fix that?
My config.yml contains:

```
      - {
          label: 'Date',
          name: 'date',
          widget: 'datetime',
          time_format: 'false',
          format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
          picker_utc: true,
        }
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdqud.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `time_format` option accepts either a *boolean* or *Moment.js tokens* (cf [documentation](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/#datetime)).

In your case, you are giving it a *string*, which it is trying to interpret as the latter (hence the weird output).

Change it to a boolean (ie: no quotes) and it should work:

```yaml
- label: 'Date'
  name: 'date_test'
  widget: 'datetime'
  time_format: false
  format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
  picker_utc: true
```